# Getting value error during fitting keras sequential model

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn

I am trying to train a keras sequential model for heart disease classification for practicing purpose. but I am getting value error, I cant understand what have I done wrong.
it saying logits and labels must have same shape, but I don't know what I need to modify.
please help me to correct the code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
from sklearn import ensemble, metrics
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

# load the boston dataset 
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
dataframe = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/heart Lab 2.csv')

# defining feature matrix(X) and response vector(y) 
X = dataframe.iloc[:,:-1] 
y = dataframe.iloc[:,-1:]

#convert categorical to numeric
labelencoder_X=LabelEncoder()
z = X.iloc[:,-1:]
X.iloc[:,-1:] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(z.values.ravel())

#z score normalization
scaller = StandardScaler()
X = scaller.fit_transform(X)

# splitting X and y into training and testing sets  
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=1) 


# define the keras model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=13, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

# compile the keras model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# fit the keras model on the dataset
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=10)

acc = model.evaluate(X_train, y_train)
print("Loss:", acc[0], " Accuracy:", acc[1])

pred = model.predict(X_test)
pred_y = pred.argmax(axis=-1)

#count_class(train_label)

cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, pred_y)
print(cm)
```

getting these error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-726f55d24365> in <module>()
     40 
     41 # fit the keras model on the dataset
---> 42 model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=10)
     43 
     44 acc = model.evaluate(X_train, y_train)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
   1127           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
   1128             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
-> 1129               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
   1130             else:
   1131               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 878, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 867, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 860, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 810, in train_step
        y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 201, in __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 141, in __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 245, in call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 1807, in binary_crossentropy
        backend.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits),
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/backend.py", line 5158, in binary_crossentropy
        return tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=target, logits=output)

    ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, 2) vs (None, 1)).
```

Comment: For classification, you need to one-hot encode the labels. Use `sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder` for that purpose.

Comment: Try changing the code in final layer `model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))` to `model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))` and try again executing the same code.